# Why does しあわせです end with です, but かなしんでいます with ます?

Tags: grammar

I'm learning a bit of Japanese with Memrise. They translate しあわせです with "is happy" and かなしんでいます with "is sad". From what I understand, adjectives are ending with です and verbs with ます. I see both expressions as opposites (happy<->sad), why do they have a different ending?

Comment: 幸せ is noun not adj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key factor here is the difference in **parts of speech** between 「しあわせ」 and 「かなしむ」.

「しあわせ」 is a noun and also a na-adjective.

「かなしむ」 is a verb.

This cold fact alone makes huge differences as to what words can surround each of the two words.

You can simply attach 「です」 to noun/na-adjectives as in 「しあわせです」, 「きれいです」, etc.

It is, however, utterly incorrect to just attach 「です」 to verbs.  You cannot say 「かなし**む**です」.  If you had the i-adjective 「かなし**い**」, however, you could just add 「です」 to it to form 「かなし**い**です」.

「かなしんでいます」 is formed from the verb 「かなし**む**」 and not the i-adjective 「かなし**い**」.

To form it, you first turn 「かなしむ」 into its te-form 「かなしんで」.  Then attach the present-progressive verb 「いる/います」 to finally form 「かなしんでいる」 or 「かなしんでいます」.  The latter is politer than the former.

What caused the confusion in your understanding this time?  I think it is none other than the fact that you "looked" at the translations too hard.  The translations were "**is happy**" and "**is sad**", respectively.  They both use the same word "**is**" so why not in Japanese?  Right?  Unintentionally, you sort of allowed the translations to fool you even though those are good and valid translations.  Please tell me if my analysis is off here.